# Negative value format with in parentheses using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want a regex which will convert using preg_replace

```
=> -1121234.56 to (1,121,234.56)
=> -1121 to (1,121.00)
=> 1121 to 1,121.00
```

Right Now I have used

```
$number = -12121234.56;
$replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);

O/P -12,121,234.56
```

I want the above features as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve with `preg_replace`, and `number_format`

```
$replace = preg_replace(
               '/(-)([\d\.\,]+)/ui',  
               '($2)',                          
               number_format($number,2,'.',',')       
           );
```

Some tests:

```
$number                     $replace
12121234.56                 12,121,234.56
-12121234.56                (12,121,234.56)
-1234567.89                 (1,234,567.89)
```

I hope this help you out.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `number_format()`:

```
function myformat($nr)
{
    $nr = number_format($nr, 2);
    return $nr[0] == '-' ? "(" . substr($nr, 1) . ")" : $nr;
}

myformat(-1121234.56);
myformat(-1121);
myformat(1121);
```

See also: [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format)

Comment: `return $nr[0] == '-' ? "($nr)" : $nr;` or `return $nr[0] == '-' ? "(".abs($nr).")" : $nr;`?